# Is it possible to use the GNOME 3 shell in Ubuntu 15.10 without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, themes

Is there any possible way to change the desktop theme in Ubuntu 15.10 to the GNOME 3 desktop theme? I would like to do this without having to uninstall Ubuntu and installing Ubuntu GNOME. I saw a way to do it for version 14.04 but it doesn't seem to apply to this version.

Comment: What way did you see, and why do you think it doesn't apply to 15.10?

Comment: It said to click on the logo to bring up different theme options but when I did nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is ambiguous.

Do you want to:

#### Install GNOME 3?:

Install the `gnome-shell`, `gnome-core` (may be installed already) and `gnome-applets` packages.

If you want *full* GNOME, install the `gnome` package.

Logout, and when you see the login screen, click on the Ubuntu logo next to your username and select GNOME 3.

> It said to click on the logo to bring up different theme options but when I did nothing happened

Nothing happened because there was *no other desktop installed*. Now there is.

#### Install Adwaita, the default GNOME 3 theme?:

Install the `gnome-themes-standard` package, then select 'Adwaita' in Settings.